# Error when using a generic type that converts an array type to a specific type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am learning new typescript concepts, in particular I am following these [challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00011-easy-tuple-to-object/README.md) to practice what I have learned.

**The challenge:**

Given an array, transform it into an object type and the key/value must be in the provided array.

**My Solution**

`type TupleToObject<T extends Array<string|number>> = { [P in T[number]]: P; };`

**My doubt**
So far so good, but when I try to do a test using this new type
[image]

I get this error on result[key]:
*"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'TupleToObject'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'TupleToObject'."*

I don't understand why I have this error in the typescript compiler. My type does not define properties of type string or number ?

if i used   let result = {} as any the error disappears.

A guide to understand the error and better understand the typescript type system

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Posting code as a screenshot generally harms people's ability to help you - if that wasn't a screenshot the first thing I'd do would be to copy it into an editor to work the problem out, but I can't (read more here: https://jakeworth.com/on-code-screenshots/). Please edit your question and replace the screenshot of your test code with the actual code itself. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) and please include any code that is necessary to understand your question as plaintext in the post itself, instead of just as a link to an external site.  We can't require that people leave SO just to see the code that makes up a question or its answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working for you.

1. Since `result` is a concrete object, you need to be specific about its type `TupleToObject<Array<string | number>>`.
2. Don't use `as` if you can avoid it. It's generally only used to skip type checking which defeats the point of TypeScript.
3. You were missing the type narrowing `if (typeof key === "string")`. Without the type narrowing, you get this error: `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

```
type TupleToObject<T extends Array<string|number>> = { [P in T[number]]: P; };

const tupleToObject = <T extends Array<string | number>>(input: T): TupleToObject<T> => {
    let result: TupleToObject<Array<string | number>> = {};

    for (const key of input) {
        if (typeof key === "string") {
            result[key] = key;
        } else {
            result[key] = key;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhGB7A8gIwFYQMbAA8MUEAHsBAHYAmAzlAIIBOzAhiIXcMwJZUBzAD5U4AW0wRmAPmlQAvFADeUANoAFKP1irREqQF0DALijqA3FAC+5gFC28qKtyjAEyNFlwEFUYqQpqeiZWDi4efgEoISg9SRlpAAp+MDhgUxgASgz3FAwcfCIYOXk5JVsoSqhkYChmCDo4RHTYXM8CgkIWdk5uPkFo2PF42V8lG3sqqAAzVGYoRMdnWoBrCBAoVGmtKlTgTOUKqarebcTQSC2oNY35O6gAIj7Ih4Py44+6hqbgVRuDXw3OyfaykRB0aDvEFVeqNZp-dYAxRAo4fKyo6wY+puZhUL5w4B2KxAA)